# How should I structure query?

Tags: mysql, sql, select, group-by, having

How do I find products that have p_option_id is 1 and 11.

```
p_id  p_option_id 
100         1  
100         2
100         3
101         1
101         2
101         11
101         12
```

This should return

```
p_id
101
```

Comment: `where p_option_id = 1 OR p_option_id = 11`? (Thanks @jarlh :) )

Comment: where p_option_id IN (1,11);

Comment: @Turnerj, I assume OR is better here, p_option_id = 1 and p_option_id = 11 will never be true...

Answer (score 7):

Try this:

```
SELECT p_id 
FROM tableA 
WHERE p_option_id IN (1, 11)
GROUP BY p_id
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT p_option_id) = 2;
```